# Detecting browser with JQuery

Tags: jquery, browser, if-statement

I am trying to use

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        if (!jQuery.browser.msie <= 7.99) {
                jQuery('#element').css('display', 'block');
        }
    });
```

But it doesn't appear to work ? What am I doing wrong ?

Thx

**Edit: Use conditional comments**

```
<!--[if !IE]>
<!--[if lt IE 8]> 

//do stuff
<![endif]-->
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: What are you trying to check for? You should use feature detection rather than browser detection if at all possible.

Comment: the standard practice would be to test for specific capabilities rather than browser behaviour. What are you trying to accomplish exactly?

Comment: Hey nick - yeah, in this case I need to check for the browsers other than IE7 ? so this was the simplest way to go [even though its depreciated]

Comment: What is the exact scenario that's failing? Does IE 8 appear to be IE7? If so ... "Note that IE8 claims to be 7 in Compatibility View" - [from the jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/)

Comment: @Tom - *Why* do you need to check for IE7? What does it have/not have that you're trying to work around?

Comment: I am trying to do - if the #element is ONLY on IE7 then leave the CSS as display:none; - otherwise in every other browser change it. This is the because the CSS renders first and the slider I am using it in is too slow to rely on JS.

Comment: well yeah - the <= 7.99 covers IE6.

Comment: ah right - its effectively the same thing right ? but too keep everrryyy one happy :) = ill use .boxModel instead which will detect for Ie6/Ie7

Comment: `<= 7.99`? Why not just `< 8` ? It might happen that there's an IE `7.999`!

Comment: You should use a CC/CSS, not support.boxModel

Comment: @Tom - You should use conditional stylesheets based on the rest of your comments, not any script at all, this will be faster as well.

Comment: Don't put the answer in your question. That's what the answers below are for. But if you insist, at least correct it so the syntax is correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`jQuery.browser.version` is what you're looking for. And you should probably `parseFloat` it.

In general though, it's looked down upon to rely on browser sniffing unless there's absolutely no way to feature detect. It might help telling us what your **real problem** is.

**EDIT: You should use conditional comments to serve rules/stylesheet(s) for IE7 and below.**

Comment: I am trying to do - if the #element is ONLY on IE7 then leave the CSS as display:none; - otherwise in every other browser change it. This is the because the CSS renders first and the slider I am using it in is too slow to rely on JS.

Comment: You can use CSS and IE Conditional statements ( not JS ).

Comment: yeah but i'd prefer not to use conditional statements as Google Pagespeed doesnt like that.

Comment: You shouldn't let an application like that tell you what you can or can't do, for practical solutions. Google shouldn't really be one telling to what code is good or not, look at gmail.. HORRIBLE coding job.

Comment: @Tom - Pagespeed is wrong in this case...if it had a check for this, it would recommend conditional stylesheets over javascript/user agent detection.

Comment: ah right ok. well, it confused the crap out of me so this is why i went looking for jquery.browser.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work from my limited testing:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  if(jQuery.browser.msie){
     if(parseFloat(jQuery.browser.version) < 8){
        //Versions of IE less than 8
        jQuery('#element').css('display', 'block');
     }
     else{
       //code for versions of IE at least 8 (currently 8 and 9)
     }
  }
  else{
     //code for browsers other than IE (Firefox Safari, chrome, Opera, etc.)
  }
});
```

Comment: hey thx. but wont this only work if MSIE - i.e. its testing for MSIE and then do stuff. I need every OTHER browser but <8 ?

Comment: @Tom I'm not sure what you are trying to do so I modified my code to show where to put code for each situation you may be trying to deal with.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't answer your specific question, but I'd propose a much simpler methodology. Use IE conditional comments to apply a specific ID to your body tag. For instance:

```
<!--[if !IE]> -->
<body>
<!--<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>
<body id="IE7">
<![endif]-->
```

Then it becomes quite trivial to detect it via jQuery:

```
if($('body').is('#IE7'))...
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use conditional comments for this, quicker, easier, shorter, like this:

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
  <style type="text/css">#element { display: none; }</style>
<![endif]-->
```

This will hide the element on IE7 and below.  You don't need *any* script to go along with this, just remove the `display: none` you currently have hiding it initially from your original stylesheet (or in-line).

For the comments concerning Google Pagespeed not liking this...ignore it, if you have to fix an IE7 bug, fix it, the right way.  This is faster and simpler...if Pagespeed was able to check that you're using the user agent to do this (which [`jQuery.browser`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/) does) it would recommend against doing so, it just doesn't have a mechanism to tell you that's a *worse* approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery.browser.msie
```

returns true or false

```
jQuery.browser.version
```

is the one to check browserversion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [jQuery Browser Plugin](http://jquery.thewikies.com/browser/). It gives you a javascript object that contains all of the information about the browser being used.
For example:

- `browser.name`: The name of the browser being used.
  `alert($.browser.name); // this will alert 'firefox'`
- browser.versionNumber`` : The version of the browser (note: as an integer).
  `alert($.browser.versionNumber); // this will alert '30'`

I personally found it really simple to use. The minified version is only 1.44KB. Please refer to the link.